# PHP json_decode() Error

Tags: php, json, syntax-error

I have a JSON string that 'is' valid JSON, according to JavaScript's JSON.parse and some online JSON validators. However, PHP's json_decode is says there is a syntax error and I for the life of me cannot find where it/they are.

Here's my JSON string, http://pastebin.com/pVLmUzQ5 (it exceeds the post length of StackOverflow)

edit:

The JSON contains some fields of this structure:

```
"pets":{"":null}
```

Edit: Something I forgot to mention was I'm pasting the JSON into a POST form and getting the data from CodeIgniter's Input::post() method with global XSS cleaning enabled. Which seems to be causing the issue. Which I was able to determine from the post below and all the posts saying PHP is decoding it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that JSON appears valid. Since we've got nothing else to go on here, there's nothing more we can do for you really.

Comment: Your JSON string is valid and PHP happily parses it. I tested all versions from 5.3 to 7.0 and none of them complains about it.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Json is correct i parse it successfully

Comment: I was able to parse your JSON successfully using PHP 7.0.8 . I then ran **json_encode** on the data, and compared the difference between the output and the original. The fields with `"": null` were replaced with `"_empty_": null`. Probably that's your issue, probably due to an older version of PHP.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention was I'm pasting the JSON into a POST form and getting the data from CodeIgniter's Input::post() method with global XSS cleaning enabled. Which seems to be causing the issue. Which I was able to determine from the post below and all the posts saying PHP is decoding it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON appears correct to me. I'm guessing you're trying to wrap the JSON in either single or double quotes which won't work because your string contains both of these characters that are unescaped.

Try wrapping your JSON in a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and then parsing it:

```
<?php

$json = <<<EOL
{"foo":"here is a single quote '"}
EOL;

$decoded = json_decode($json);
var_dump($decoded);
```

Please replace my example JSON with yours.

Comment: I'm not actually manually pasting in the string. I take the string from an iFrame from the site it comes from and paste it into a <textarea> inside a form (POST request) - then pull it from CodeIgniter's input::post (); method to XSS clean it... and I just found it's CodeIgniter that's causing the problem, probably the XSS clean... Ugh...

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. That sounds like it may be the issue! If you're still having trouble, please update your question and provide as much detail as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the HEREDOC information though. I may end up using that in the future for some stuff. The only issue now is the XSS cleaning, which I'd like to keep, but CI doesn't allow for any exceptions it's an all or nothing. So I either have to disable it completely or look for an alternative solution. Thanks again. :)